# Using argument char argv[] in system()

Tags: c++, arguments, command-line-arguments

I need to execute a perl script from my c++ code. This is done with system().
Now I need to pass the second argument from my code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

into my system() like this:

```
char *toCall="perl test.pl "+argv[1];
system(toCall);
```

Now it brings the error: "invalid operands of types ‘const char [14]’ and ‘char**’ to binary ‘operator+’"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is utterly unsafe; what if argv[1] was `; /bin/rm -rf $HOME`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: you are right, but we don't know if the OP has planned to add some input checking; showing it here would not have made the question any clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `std::string`, like

```
std::string const command = std::string( "perl test.pl " ) + argv[1];
system( command.c_str() );
```

You cannot add two raw pointers.

But `std::string` provides an overload of the `+` operator.

Comment: Technically the first is a `const char[]`, but indeed it does boil down to it trying to add the decayed pointer from that.

Comment: This make a security hole: `./script 'myarg && echo hello'` will execute ./script with myarg and print hello.

Comment: @Xorax: see [Doc Brown's earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674721/using-argument-char-argv-in-system/10674740?noredirect=1#comment13850347_10674721).

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a concatentated string by assigning `char*`. You need to use `std::string` or `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream s;

s << "perl test.pl";
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    // Space to separate arguments.
    // You need to quote the arguments if
    // they can contain spaces.
    s << " " << argv[i];
}

system(s.str().c_str());
```